# Why would my C# app fail on this REST request but but works fine through a browser?

Tags: c#, json, rest, httpurlconnection, dotnet-httpclient

I have a C# app and I am accessing some data over REST so I pass in a URL to get a JSON payload back.  I access a few different URLs programmatically and they all work fine using this code below **except one call**.

Here is my code:

```
 var url = "http://theRESTURL.com/rest/API/myRequest";
 var results = GetHTTPClient().GetStringAsync(url).Result;
 var restResponse = new RestSharp.RestResponse();
 restResponse.Content = results;
 var _deserializer = new JsonDeserializer();
```

where GetHTTPClient() is using this code below:

```
private HttpClient GetHTTPClient()
{
  var httpClient = new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler()
  {
     Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("usr", "pwd"),
     UseDefaultCredentials = false,
     UseProxy = true,
     Proxy = new WebProxy(new Uri("http://myproxy.com:8080")),
     AllowAutoRedirect = false
  });
  httpClient.Timeout = new TimeSpan(0,0, 3500);
  return httpClient;
 }
```

so as i said, the above code works fine but a bunch of different request but for one particular request, I am getting an exception inside of the

```
 .GetStringAsync(url).Result
```

call with the error:

**Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host**

I get that error after waiting for about 10 minutes.  What is interesting is that if I put that same URL that isn't working into Internet Explorer directly I do get the JSON payload back (after about 10 minutes as well).  So i am confused at why

- It would work fine directly from the browser but fail when using the code above.
- It fails on this one request but other requests using the same code work fine programmatically.

Any suggestions for things to try or things I should ask the owner of the server to check out on their end to help diagnose what is going on?

Comment: inspect what request the browser is issuing.

Comment: Most likely a header/negotiation or maybe timeout issue. I usually use [fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) to do this kind of inspection.

Comment: Try to avoid using `Task.Result`, it may end up with a deadlock which may be the culprit here, instead `await` the task to get its result.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen - can you give me an example of what you are talking about?

Comment: You would write that line of code like this: `var results = await GetHTTPClient().GetStringAsync(url);` This would mean the method this line is in would have to be async as well, but see here for more information: [Don't Block on Async Code](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html).

Comment: Check with fiddler the server response. Is your proxy accessible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the timeout is not an issue here, as the error states that connection has been closed remotely and the set timeout is about 58 minutes, which is more than enough compared to your other figures.

Have you tried looking at the requests itself? Might want to edit your question with those results.

Comment: I agree that my timeout length is much higher than i am getting this error. Can you clarify your question "looking at the requests itself?".  what are you suggesting?

Comment: Use fiddler to exactly see what your request headers look like, simply compare the headers of the browser and app request. Also, as suggested, check the proxy involved.

Comment: It turned out that there was a different proxy being used in my REST call versus the browser.  Once i corrected that it worked as expected

Answer (score 0):

If you remove line `httpClient.Timeout = new TimeSpan(0,0, 3500);` the issue should be solved but if the request would last 20 minutes you should wait all the time.

Comment: I don't understand this as my timeout period is much larger than 20 minutes?

Comment: Sorry! I had read 350. 350 seconds are 5 minutes as it was written in your question. My fault. 20 minutes was an example. However, have you tried to remove that line?